# Formmating Websocket data with Json Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, websocket, format

I am receiving data from a website via websocket however sometimes the websocket turns out to be empty outputting in `{}`. How can I give out a filter so that I only get the outputs of the data that is not empty. The `if data != '{}'` function does not work what could i do so that the function is valid?

```
import websocket
import pprint
import json 

while True: 
   data= ws.fetch(dataset)
   if data != '{}':
      pprint.pprint(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the length of the data

```
if len(data)>0
```

`len(someDict)` outputs number of items in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the "**W**hile" to "**w**hile".

Try this:

```
if data:
    pprint.pprint(data)
```